# How to correlate Camel ExchangeCompletedEvent and multicast/split?

Tags: apache-camel, jbossfuse, fuseesb

I have a scenario where I use ExchangeCompleteEvent to print some log.

I have Multicast in my Route as below :-

```
from("{{route.from}}")
.multicast()
.to("{{route.to1}}")
.to("{{route.to2}}");
```

The ExchangeCompleteEvent is called 3 times in such case. I think two are for above two .to calls and one is for main exchange.

I want to use it only for main exchange i.e the last call, how can I correlate the ExchangeCompleteEvent with main exchange ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The child exchanges will have an exchange property stored (key is the field `Exchange.CORRELATION_ID`, eg `CamelCorrelationId`) which point to their parent exchange id. So you can look for that property to see if its present or not. If not then its the parent exchange.

Comment: Thanks Claus for your idea.
I have implemented it in my business case it worked well.
Great Thanks !

-Rahul

Answer (score 0):

One solution could be to tag (with a Camel header or property) the multicasted copies, but not the master message. Then you could test the presence of such header/property to know whether the completed exchange is the master exchange or not.
The "`onPrepareRef`" should help to assign the tag.

```
from("{{route.from}}")
.multicast()
.onPrepare( exchange -> exchange.getIn().setHeader("isChild", "Y") )
.to("{{route.to1}}")
.to("{{route.to2}}");
```

Comment: Thanks for your response,your idea would work defiantly but we are developing some common frameworks and do not want any such kind of thing in integration itself. The bellow suggestion worked well using the correlation Id.